# Custom Label as Master Lable

Tags: custom-object, custom-button, customlabel

I'm trying to find a way to make a button label dynamic and I couldn't find any other way than Custom Label. The only issue is I don't know how to make the MasterLabel to pick my custom label. I've tried these codes and no luck so far.

My custom label is 'Job'

```
 <masterLabel>{!System.Label.Job}</masterLabel>
```

I also tried these:

```
 <masterLabel>{!$Label.Job}</masterLabel>
 <masterLabel>$Label.Job</masterLabel>
 <masterLabel>System.Label.Job</masterLabel>
```

None worked :(